# How to export key/value pair variables from a file inside makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

How to set the variables - key/value pair from a text file before running any targets in a Makefile?

Let's say text **.p4config** file contains the following:
`P4PORT=ilp4.il.domain.com:1667 P4CLIENT=ws:domain.com::user:container.IP_V1:a0a12fc1`

in makefile this wont work:

`export $(cat .p4config | grep P4CLIENT | xargs) test: env > env.log`

Expecting to see the variables P4PORT and P4CLIENT in the env.log

`cat .p4config | grep P4CLIENT | xargs`

results:

`P4PORT=ilp4.il.domain.com:1667 P4CLIENT=ws:domain.com::user:container.IP_V1:a0a12fc1`

but adding the "export" inside the makefile won't do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this can achieve what you expected :

```
.ONESHELL:

all:
    eval "$$(perl -ne 'if (/P4CLIENT/) { map {print "export $$_\n"} split }' .p4config)"
    env | grep P4
```

output of `env | grep P4`:

```
P4CLIENT=ws:domain.com::user:container.IP_V1:a0a12fc1
P4PORT=ilp4.il.domain.com:1667
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you thought that would work.  A makefile is not a shell script, so you can't just write a bunch of shell operations in it an expect to behave the same way.  The syntax of a makefile is described in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).

A makefile can CONTAIN a shell script, but only inside a recipe.  So you could put the same command you'd type at the command line, into a recipe:

```
env.log:
        cat .p4config | grep P4CLIENT | xargs > $@
```

Now if you type `make env.log` (or any other target that lists `env.log` as a prerequisite) make will create that file for you (of course, note the indentation here must be a real TAB character, not just spaces).

Comment: The question was not to create the env.log but to have the variables set for other commands in the recipe. I need those variables set as they were set before running the makefile.